# Error: Class 'path' Is not compliant with PSR-4 configuration

Tags: psr-4, phpcs

I am trying PHP coding standard package: https://github.com/inpsyde/php-coding-standards, but when I start running phpcs, I get:

```
nickan@nickan-VirtualBox:~/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin$ vendor/bin/phpcs ./src/model/Users.php 
E 1 / 1 (100%)



FILE: /home/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/src/model/Users.php
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 | ERROR | Class 'Plugin\Model\Users', located at
   |       | '/home/src/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/src/model/Users.php', is not
   |       | compliant with PSR-4 configuration. (Inpsyde.CodeQuality.Psr4.InvalidPSR4)
```

Here is the file in path `my-plugin/src/model/Users.php`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Model;

class Users
{

}
```

I don't get what's wrong, the code is working fine but the error keeps showing up. I tried to have different namespacing, changing the folder, etc, still to no avail, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the output as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 5):

PSR-4 demands (among other stuff) that the namespace directly corresponds to the directory structure. This is case sensitive.

Long story short: You need to name your directory `src/Model/Users.php` with a capital M.

Also, your namespace does not have a vendor prefix as demanded by PSR-4. The sniff would not be able to detect that, but you should still fix that.

Answer (score 4):

The issue maybe because of the following configurations. Please make sure you have added the correct configurations

```
    <rule ref="Inpsyde.CodeQuality.Psr4">
    <properties>
        <property
            name="psr4"
            type="array"
            value="Inpsyde\MyProject=>wp-content/plugins/inpsyde-task-plugin/InpsydeTaskPlugin.php,InpsydeTests=>tests/InpsydeTests"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```